# Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 problem (Not detecting Windows)

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, 14.10

My ubuntu Grub not detecting my Windows 7 after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10. What should i do?

Comment: How can I repair grub ^^

Comment: Follow the link in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Ubuntu [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool and guide?